# Implementation of Chan's algorithm performing worse than Graham Scan and Jarvis March

Tags: algorithm, performance, geometry, big-o, convex-hull

I'm trying to implement some 2D convex hull algorithms (Jarvis March, Graham's Scan, and Chan's) in C#. I read the Wikipedia pages and implemented the given pseudocode in c#. All 3 implementations return correct results, and Jarvis March and Graham Scan mostly perform according to expectations (O(NH), O(NlogN), respectively), but Chan's perform much worse than the expected O(NlogH) time (much slower than Graham's scan and barely faster than Jarvis March, if at all, at n = 10,000 and random h mostly between 16(2^2^2) and 256(2^2^3)). I can't find what's wrong with my code that causes this. Any help would be appreciated. Assuming my code for the first 2 algorithms is correct, below is my code for Chan's:

```java
public static List<Vertex> TimothyChan(List<Vertex> vertices){
  if (vertices.Count <= 3) return vertices;
  Vertex previous = vertices[0];
  foreach (var point in vertices.Where(point => point.CompareTo(previous) < 0)) previous = point;
  List<Vertex> operatingVertices = new List<Vertex>(vertices);
  List<List<Vertex>> subsetVertices = new List<List<Vertex>>();
  List<Vertex> hullVertices = new List<Vertex>();
  List<List<Vertex>> subsetHullVertices = new List<List<Vertex>>();
  List<Vertex> candidates = new List<Vertex>();      
  for (int t = 1; ; t++){
    int estimateHullVerticesCount = (int) Math.Min(Math.Pow(2,Math.Pow(2, t)), operatingVertices.Count);
    int subsetCount = operatingVertices.Count / estimateHullVerticesCount;         
    subsetVertices.Clear();
    for (int j = 0; j < subsetCount; j++) subsetVertices.Add(j < subsetCount - 1 ? 
      operatingVertices.GetRange(j * estimateHullVerticesCount, estimateHullVerticesCount) :
      operatingVertices.GetRange(j * estimateHullVerticesCount, operatingVertices.Count - j * estimateHullVerticesCount));
      subsetHullVertices.Clear();
      foreach (var subset in subsetVertices) subsetHullVertices.Add(RonaldGraham(subset));
      for (int j = 0; j < estimateHullVerticesCount; j++){
        hullVertices.Add(previous);                
        candidates.Clear();
        foreach (var subset in subsetHullVertices) candidates.Add(JarvisMarchNextVertex(previous, subset));        
        previous = JarvisMarchNextVertex(previous, candidates);
        if (previous.Equals(hullVertices[0])) return hullVertices.ToList();
      }
      operatingVertices.Clear();
      foreach (var subsetHullVertex in subsetHullVertices) operatingVertices.AddRange(subsetHullVertex);
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:** updated code to preallocate lists and clear each loop instead of using new each loop. It's now somewhat faster (noticeably faster than Jarvis march, but still significantly slower than graham scan)

**Edit 2:** I realized I didn't have to clear the hullVertices list every time the estimateHullVerticesCount is updated.

**Edit 3:** Removed non subset hull vertices from consideration in the next loop. Still somewhat slower than graham scan

**Edit 4:** Duh-Doy! `RonaldGraham()` returns an ordered list of counterclockwise subset convex hull vertices. Since these are ordered, I should use a `JarvisMarchBinarySearch` algorithm with a time complexity of O(logm) for the innermost loop, instead of a linear complexity `JarvisMarchNextVertex` algorithm. Now if I can just figure out how to implement the binary search that achieves O(logm)...

Comment: All those `new` must be hurt the performance, can you pre-allocate them before the loop and reuse?

Comment: @Surt thanks for your comment. I can preallocate some of them and replace with clear but aren't some unavoidable because each cycle would have a different number of them? For example the lists containing subset vertices. Also my other 2 algorithms also didn't preallocate (but they also have fewer loops). In any case I'll try that and come back to you.

Comment: Due to the higher asymptotic constant, It could be that Chan's algorithm is only faster for H larger than 10 millions. Who knows ? As regards asymptotic complexity, measuring with N=10000 is often ridiculously small. Asymptotically efficient does not always mean fast.

Comment: You only need to reset the used entries in the lists, you could do that just before ending the loop.

Comment: @Surt I moved the clear() calls. Doing so only saved 2 ```clear()``` calls of each list at most tho so it didn't make much of a difference. Though removing the ```new``` calls definitely makes a noticeable difference. a lot of the ```new``` calls are hidden in ```RonaldGraham()``` and ```GetRange()``` though and the only way I can think of to get rid of them would be to instead use 2D ```Vertex[,]``` matrices maybe?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Wow I didn't know that. Do you have any readings on that that I could study?

Comment: @Joe: sorry, nothing in particular. Mostly experience.

Comment: Fairly sure Chan's algorithm is slower due to higher overhead unless you have a truly large number of points.  As Yves pointed out. I typically prefer Andrew's algorithm when it comes to convex hulls if I feel need to write my own. Doesn't hurt that you can find the implementation in quite a few languages here and it's pretty straightforward to implement unlike some of the others: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain